# How can you use DynamoDb Persistence Adapter in Pyhon SDK

Tags: python, alexa-skills-kit

Could somebody give me some sample code to use DynamoDb Persistence Adapter in Python?

Here are the official docs but I can't figure out how to use this.
https://alexa-skills-kit-python-sdk.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api/dynamodb_persistence.html

Thank you.

Comment: Im not familiar with DynamoDB as well.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, you need to create a table in DynamoDB, you can do so through the AWS console.

Then create an AWS access key and secret pair from your AWS account. You will need these to authenticate and connect to Dynamo from the skill code.

Then, in your code, setup the connection after an invocation, you can put this in an interceptor or at the start of every handler.

```
import boto3
from ask_sdk_dynamodb.adapter import DynamoDbAdapter, user_id_partition_keygen

dynamodb = boto3.resource('dynamodb',
                          region_name="eu-west-1",
                          aws_access_key_id="your_access_key",
                          aws_secret_access_key="your_secret_key")
dynamo_client = DynamoDbAdapter(table_name="your_table_name",
                                partition_key_name="user_id",  # the ID you choose while creating the table
                                partition_keygen=user_id_partition_keygen,  # default
                                create_table=False,  # default
                                dynamodb_resource=dynamodb)
```

As you can see, I specified the `user_id_partition_keygen`, which is the default, this means that each item stored in your table will use the UserId as main ID, so you won't be able to have two items for the same user, you can change this with whatever suits you.

After the connection is set you can just store an attributes dictionary, that in this case will be connected to the userId, or read the user's attributes.

```
# Store attributes for the user
attr = {
    'last_request_time': datetime.now().strftime("%Y%m%d"),
}
self.dynamo_client.save_attributes(request_envelope=handler_input.request_envelope, attributes=attr)

# Get user attributes
user_attr = self.dynamo_client.get_attributes(request_envelope=handler_input.request_envelope)
```